# Javascript Map.get not returning correct value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've found other questions that express difficulties with the Map.get method but nothing exactly like what I'm experiencing.

So I have the following code that attempts to sort data from an Array into a tree structure (implemented via nested Maps). If anyone knows a better way to do this altogether then I'm all ears. I'm a Javascript beginner and this is the best I could come up with. I'm open to the possibility that this may be an entirely unworkable approach.

The problem occurs where I try and use get on a map instance it returns another map object, where, as far as I can tell, it should be returning an array that contains a map. This is must easier to show than explain, which I'll attempt to do by posting the code below and then highlighting the parts of my debugging log that I can't make heads or tails of.

I should also note I'm using TypeScript, but as far as I understand that shouldn't make any difference.

The code is as follows:

```
let test_keys = ["ParentA", "ChildAA", "GrandChildAAA"];

let fake_content = {stuff: "stuff"};

const mainmap = new Map();

add_map_data(mainmap, test_keys, fake_content);

function add_map_data(map: Map<string, typeof Array>, keys: Array<string>, data: Object)
{
    const LAST = keys.length-1
    let i = 0;
    let mref = null;

    for (i=0; i < keys.length; i++)
    {
        console.log("Now checking " + i + " - " + keys[i]);

        if (i == 0)
            if (mainmap.has(keys[i]))
            {
                mref = mainmap.get(keys[i]);
                console.log("   '" + keys[i] + "' *already* in main map & mref set accordingly");
            }
            else
            {
                mainmap.set(keys[i], [new Map(), null]);
                mref = mainmap.get(keys[i]);
                console.log("   '" + keys[i] + "' added to main map & mref set accordingly");
            }

        else
        {
            let c = 0;
            for (c=0; c<=i; c++)
            {
                if (c > 0)
                {
                    console.log("\n");
                    console.log("\t - inspecting mref: " + mref);
                    console.log("\n");
                    console.log("\t - mref[0].has(" + keys[c] + ") = " + mref[0].has(keys[c]));
                    if (mref[0].has(keys[c]))
                    {
                        mref = mref[0].get(keys[c]);
                        console.log("\t'" + keys[c] + "' *already* in parent node & mref set accordingly");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        mref[0].set(keys[c], [new Map(), null]);
                        console.log("\n");
                        console.log("\t - inspecting NEW mref: " + mref);
                        console.log("\t   - mref[0].get(" + keys[c] + "): " + mref[0].get(keys[c]));
                        mref = mref[0].get(keys[c]);
                        console.log("\t   - " + mref);
                        console.log("\n");
                        console.log("\t - '" + keys[c] + "' added to parent node as [new Map(), null] & mref set accordingly\n");
                    }
                }
                else console.log("\t - skipping first key item as it has been dealt with")
            }
        }
        if (i == LAST)
        {
            if (mref != null)
            {
                mref[1] = data;
                console.log("\t\t'" + keys[i] + "' updated to contain data-block");
            }
            else console.log("On last pass, mref was equal to null");
        }
    }
    console.log("\n");
}
```

My log is as follows:

```
Now checking 0 - ParentA

   'ParentA' added to main map & mref set accordingly

Now checking 1 - ChildAA

         - skipping first key item as it has been dealt with

         - inspecting mref: [object Map],

         - mref[0].has(ChildAA) = false

         - inspecting NEW mref: [object Map],
           - mref[0]: [object Map]
           - mref[0].get(ChildAA): [object Map],
           - [object Map],

         - 'ChildAA' added to parent node as [new Map(), null] & mref set accordingly

Now checking 2 - GrandChildAAA

         - skipping first key item as it has been dealt with

         - inspecting mref: [object Map],

         - mref[0].has(ChildAA) = false

         - inspecting NEW mref: [object Map],
           - mref[0]: [object Map]
           - mref[0].get(ChildAA): [object Map],
           - [object Map],

         - 'ChildAA' added to parent node as [new Map(), null] & mref set accordingly

         - inspecting mref: [object Map],

         - mref[0].has(GrandChildAAA) = false

         - inspecting NEW mref: [object Map],
           - mref[0]: [object Map]
           - mref[0].get(GrandChildAAA): [object Map],
           - [object Map],

         - 'GrandChildAAA' added to parent node as [new Map(), null] & mref set accordingly

                'GrandChildAAA' updated to contain data-block
```

Now where my log refers to `inspecting NEW ref` during the `ChildAA` portion of the loop, I am completely lost as to how `mref[0].get(ChildAA)` could possibly return `[object Map]`, (which is the same return value as `mref[0]` right above it).

This is the causing the whole purpose of the loop to fail, as subsequent passes don't refer to the correct value!

Apologies in advance if this is some obvious thing I've missed. I have completely cooked my brain trying to diagnose this today...

Comment: _"it returns another map object"_ - No, it doesn't. It returns an array containing a `Map` and `null`. This array is then used in a string which implicitly calls `.toString()` on the array. The `Map` will end as `[object Map]` and `null` as an empty string (`[null].toString() === ""`). These two strings will then be joined (`.join()`), hence the lonely `,` after `[object Map]` -> `[new Map(), null].toString() === "[object Map],"`

Comment: "*I am completely lost as to how `mref[0].get(ChildAA)` could possibly return `[object Map]`, (which is the same return value as `mref[0]` right above it).*" It **doesn't** return `[object Map]` what it actually shows is `"[object Map],"` the *string* that says `[object Map]` (a string value), followed by a comma. You get that because you are using string concatenation with `mref` - an array which is `[new Map(), null]`. String concatenation turns the array to a string so you get the `toString()` of the map, and an empty string from the second index, these are joined with a comma.

Comment: Legends. Thank you! Is there a way to log the array correctly in the same line as a string?

Comment: `console.log("Now checking, i, keys[i])` will give you the "correct" results

Comment: Cheers for that. Now that that's cleared up I need to work out why `mref[0].has(ChildAA)` is returning false on its second pass.

Comment: I suggest stepping through this code with a debugger. Right now it's hard to follow exactly what's happening. I did put a breakpoint there and the reason `.has()` returns `false` is because...the element isn't there. The map is infact empty. I haven't traced why, however.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you. I'll investigate further and post an update once I figure it out :)